# AngularJS edit mode css

Tags: css, angularjs, razor, model-view-controller

On the following site:http://www.jgdoherty.org/ when "Edit" is clicked (it takes a few seconds for the rows to populate) the cells become padded. I want to remove this effect or at least reduce the padding. I assume it is a bootstrap class that is causing it (the page has a link to bootstrap.css) so I need to hack bootstrap.css to fix it but I have been unable to find the line of code that creates the padding.
The html that creates the table in the page is  as follows:

```
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:800px">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>PostalCode</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr><tr data-ng-repeat="hotel in hotels">
        <td><strong data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.FriendId }}</strong></td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.FirstName }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.FirstName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.LastName }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.LastName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.Address }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.Address" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.City }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.City" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.PostalCode }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.PostalCode" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.Country }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.Country" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode">{{ hotel.Notes }}</p>
            <input data-ng-show="hotel.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="hotel.Notes" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p data-ng-hide="hotel.editMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(hotel)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="deletefriend(hotel)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
            <p data-ng-show="hotel.editMode"><a data-ng-click="save(hotel)" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(hotel)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can use your browser developer tools to inspect the element and see exactly which classes are applied to the element and what styles belong in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Goivanni. His answers helped.
This works:
Adding a class to the "input" html object like so

```
<input class="width_60" />
```

The class is below

```
.width_60
{
 width: 60px; 
}
```

The code below also does what I need. You must place it in the controller method as you can see. I added "**$element**" to the arguments in the brackets and also the line "**$element.parent().find('input').css('width', '60px');**  " to the function body.

```
 function hotelController($scope, Hotel, $element) { 
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.addMode = false;
        $scope.hotels = Hotel.query();
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.toggleEdit = function (hotel) {
            id = hotel.HotelId;
            $element.parent().find('input').css('width', '60px');   


        this.hotel.editMode = !this.hotel.editMode;
    };
```

Comment: In that case, why you didn't simply add a class that set the width to 60px to all input elements?

Comment: Yes using a class works  also. By adding an id to the input tag like this " <input id="cls1" > and adding a class  #cls1 {
        width:60px;      
    }

Comment: Instead an id, it should be a class: <input class="width_60" /> and .width_60{ width: 60px; }

Comment: Cool.. This proved to be easier than it looked :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything is been added by `bootstrap`. It's when you edit, your `input` fields appear. They are bigger in `height` and `width` than your `<p>`. Which means it will automatically expand. The `<td>` also has a padding of `8px`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
angular.element('p.ng-binding').each(function() {
    self = angular.element(this)
    self.parent().find('input').css('width', self.width());
});
```

Comment: I tried Giovanni's code; it didn't do what I want but it's a start.

Comment: I think this will be useful if you have different column widths instead of 60px each one